# How to use picker view value in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, picker

I have a picker view and it works well, but I don't know how to use the picked value.
I'd like to print the selected value on each selectedValue1.text and selectedValue2.text.

my array(arr) has 21 index from 0 to 20.

for example,
in the left picker view, you select 1 and in the right picker view, you select 10 then,
selectedValue1.text should show 1 and selectedValue.text should show 10. I'd like it to work this way.

```
class Setup: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var selectedValue1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedValue2: UILabel!

     var selectRow = 0

        var numbers = arr

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return numbers[row]

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectRow = row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can set a tag on your `picker view` in `viewDidLoad` like this

```
self.leftPickerView.tag = 1 // here you have to use your pickerview
self.rightPickerView.tag = 2 // here you have to use your pickerview
```

> Or you can set the leftPickerView's tag as 1 and set 2 for the rightPickerView under the "Attributes Inspector".

And then try like this

```
var numbers = ["1","2","3"]
var otherDataset = ["10","20","30"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return numbers.count
   }else{
        return otherDataset.count  
   }  
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return numbers[row]
   }else{
        return otherDataset[row]  
   }  


}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
       // set the value to selectedValue1
       self.selectedValue1.text = numbers[row] // you should write in your way
    } else {
        self.selectedValue2.text = otherDataset[row] // you should write in your way
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arryOfNumbers = ["1","2","3"]
 var arryOfValue = ["Red","Blue","Orange"]

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  selectedValue1.text = arryOfNumbers[row]
  selectedValue2.text = arryOfValue[row]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1- In "didSelectRow" method use this code

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) { 
if pickerView == leftPickerView {
    selectedValue1.text = numbers[row]
  }}
```

2- Make a toolbar above Picker and add a button on toolbar. So, when user press that button you can use the following code in button action

```
selectedValue1.text = numbers[selectedRow]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make control in this function.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if(_pickerView == pickerView1)//whatever you gave the picker name
        {
            selectedValue1.text = array[row].blabla
        }else
        {
            selectedValue2.text = array[row].blabla
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example,     myCurrency is an array, activeCurrency is just a normal integer value. I hope you understand how to show pickerData, just examine this.
didSelectRow we get pickerData then we store it inside our integer value.

Basically in your case you have to modify your didSelectRow function 
selected row must be equals to your array but you are not initialized any array first you have to create an array.

```
extension  ConverterController:  UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return myCurrency[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return myCurrency.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    activeCurrency = myValues[row]
}}
```